# trying to count how many times a script inside a function is used

Tags: python, function

I am trying to use a counter how many times an object moves. There is two functions, the first one is [here](http://pastebin.com/3EcmS7pP), the second one is [here](http://pastebin.com/ts7GvGtJ).

Here's the question:
Create a new subroutine `CalculateDistance`, which works out the distance between the cell currently occupied by M and the cell currently occupied by *.

Basically, I have to display the amount of moves it takes for M to reach *. I thought the most logical way of doing this would be to call `MakeMonsterMove` inside the new subroutine `CalculateDistance` as the exam paper says that is what we have to do. Then, using this algorithm:

```
MonsterMoves = 0
while loop
    call MakeMonsterMove
    MonsterMoves = MonsterMoves+1
print(MonsterMoves+1)
```

My logic is that each time the monster moves using the signalled subroutine, the counter will add one each time. However, whilst playing the game, the counter is always 1.Even when the M moves, it neither increases or decreases.

I'm using Python 3.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure that the monsterawake==True condition is just not initially false, and that possibly your CalculateDistance just never goes to the loop in the first place?

Comment: I thought about this, but the actual program is a skeleton program by my exam board and its damn hard to find stuff. They have some logic at the top where `self.MonsterAwake = Logical()` and the only other times `MonsterAwake` is called, it is done using `MonsterAwake.Is`. I can't actually find where the variable, `MonsterAwake` can be initialised from, but of course I don't want to call if it is false. The whole program is found [here](http://pastebin.com/h9uCDWvx) with my additions as this is my mock exam code, this is the last question :)

Comment: It actually is initialized in that line. `self.monsterAwake` is essentially instance of The `Logical` class that has variable `monsterAwake.Is` that's initialized to `False`. Which would indicate that it is initially false, and if it's never changed to true it would continue being false. It is also set to false at `SetUpGame` but with quick skimming I didnt find a line where it would ever change, which probably means your while loop is never executed.

Comment: Actually on another thought, your condition should actually probably check for monsterawake.is inatead of monsterawake.